# Why is R HTTR content statement not producing the expected request body?

Tags: r, api, mime-types, httr

I am using R to call on Cybersource API. When I use the GET request I obtain a successful response of 200. When I read the body of the the response rather than get the csv data  back I get a path to a csv file path. I wonder what I am doing wrong.

`content(request)` gives

```
 "/space/download_reports/output/dailyreports/reports/2018/10/27/testrest/TRRReport-7931d82d-cf4a-71fa-e053-a2588e0ab27a.csv"
```

The result of `content(request)` should be the data not a file path.

Here is a the code

```r
library('httr')
merchant<-'testrest'
vcdate<-'Wed, 29 May 2019 10:09:48 GMT'
ho<-'apitest.cybersource.com'
URL<-'https://apitest.cybersource.com/reporting/v3/report-downloads?organizationId=testrest&reportDate=2018-10-27&reportName=TRRReport'
sign<-'keyid="08c94330-f618-42a3-b09d-e1e43be5efda", algorithm="HmacSHA256", headers="host (request-target) v-c-merchant-id", signature="7cr6mZMa1oENhJ5NclGsprmQxwGlo1j3VjqAR6xngxk="'
req<-GET(URL, add_headers(.headers=c('v-c-merchant-id'=merchant, 'v-c-date'=vcdate, 'Host'=ho, 'Signature'=sign)))
content(req)
```

Here is Cybersource test api where you can verify the data produced.

https://developer.cybersource.com/api/reference/api-reference.html

I am trying to download a report under the reporting tab

Comment: Have you tried using `download.file` or whatever other function to download the file now that you have the link?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Are you sure the response is supposed to be the data? It seems like maybe it's trying to send you a redirect. Can you quote the relevant parts of the API documentation?

Comment: No i havent. i am literrally using the get request to call the api and contenet(request) to read the body mof ythe api. In postman it shows me a  a csv data rather than a path. How do i use download.file. Also /space/download_reports/output/dailyreports/reports/2018/10/27/testrest/TRRReport-7931d82d-cf4a-71fa-e053-a2588e0ab27a.csv does not look like a URL path

Comment: That looks like a relative path. I suspect the root is similar to the one you are accessing for the other API calls. As far as using `download.file`, have you tried `?download.file`?

Comment: Not sure how i use ?download.file in the httr GET Request. I have edited my question and posted my code. @MrFlick Yes its supposed to be data. I have tested this in postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I'm not exactly sure what's going on here, but I do think I was able to get something to work.

The API seems to like to return data in `application/hal+json` format which is not one that `httr` normally requests. You can say you'll accept anything with  `accept("*")` So you can do your request with:

```
req <- GET(URL, add_headers('v-c-merchant-id'=merchant, 
  'v-c-date'=vcdate, 
  'Host'=ho, 
  'Signature'=sign), accept("*"))
```

Now we are actually getting the data back that we want, but `httr` doesn't know how to automatically parse it. So we need to parse it ourselves. This seems to do the trick

```
readr::read_csv(rawToChar(content(req)), skip=1)
```

There seems to be a header row which we skip with `skip=` and then we parse the rest as a CSV file with `readr::read_csv`.